# pycharm use pyside2 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, pycharm, pyside2

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel
print(sys.argv)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    dates = QApplication(sys.argv)
    label = QLabel('hello world')
    label.show()
    sys.exit(dates.exec_())
```

ERROR

```
['E:/MayaTool/glTools/test.py']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/MayaTool/glTools/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    dates = QApplication(sys.argv)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

**
This code runs in python with its own editor but it complains in Pycharm. What's the problem？
**

Comment: You're saying it runs when you copy and paste the code verbatim in IDLE but not in PyCharm?

Comment: What specific version of pycharm are you using? Try upgarding to the latest version - or if you're alreading using that, try downgrading to an earleir version - and check whether the problem persists.

Answer (score 2):

You probably added the MayaDevKit code compilation for PyMel which contains PySide2 stand-ins to your environment. Removing it should solve your problem.

Comment: I guess you mean "code completions". Had the same issue. I added the maya devkit completions to the interpreter paths. So when running it through PyCharm with the mayapy.exe interpreter it used those paths to find QApplication which returns an empty class. As Eoyilmaz said, just remove it from the interpreter paths and that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

As seen [here](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QApplication.html), the initialisation of the `QApplication` class takes in the arguments passed when running the Python script as `sys.argv`. As you have suspected, when run in IDLE there are arguments passed to the program, but when in PyCharm there are no (0) arguments passed, so `sys.argv` returns `None`. The initialisation of `QApplication` attempts to iterate through the list of arguments as it expects a `list` of string (the arguments).

An easy fix would be to check if `sys.argv` is `None`, e.g.

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel
print(sys.argv)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if sys.argv is None:
        sys.argv = []
    dates = QApplication(sys.argv)
    label = QLabel('hello world')
    label.show()
    sys.exit(dates.exec_())
```

Comment: one line: `QApplication(sys.argv or [])`

Comment: This makes no sense. Why would `sys.argv` ever be `None`? It [should always be](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) at least `['']`. There is also no reason why pyside/pyqt would attempt to treat the passed in argument as a callable. It seems much more likely that this is caused by a bug in pycharm - perhaps related to [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-36726).

Comment: Just to be clear: executing `QApplication(None)` in either PyQt5 or PySide2 does not raise the exception shown in the question.